# How to add items from fragment to sql and spinner in android

Tags: android, sql-server, android-fragments, android-spinner

Please help, can't solve this. I can't add items from fragment to my sql database and to spinner in another class. The main idea is to add items permanently to spinner (or until I manually delete it) so when I close my app and open it again it should be there. I am beginner and I can't find solution to this problem. I checked lots of similar posts but I am really confused and don't know how to make it work. Here is some of my code:

I created spinner in my main activity:

```
spinner= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    loadSpinnerData();

    public void loadSpinnerData() {
            MyDBHandler db = new MyDBHandler (getApplication());
            ArrayList<projectNames> list = db.getAllLabels();
            ArrayAdapter<projectNames> adapterFrom = new ArrayAdapter<projectNames>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list)
            {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
                {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                // Get item at position
                projectNames model = getItem(position);
                // Set textview's value with the category name
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                textView.setText(model.get_name());

                return view;
                }
            };
            adapterFrom.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapterFrom);
     }
```

Now when I open new dialog fragment I want on buttonclick to add items to spinner in previous class and to my SQL database (or to my SQL and then from it to spinner - whatever is better/easyer):

Code for Sql:

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="projects.db";
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS="projects";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID="_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME="name";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

I got rest of regular methods for Sql but don't want to post it here atm becouse it will be bunch of code. If something is needed, please ask.

Code I have so far for adding items to spinner from fragment:

```
MainActivity newSpinner = new MainActivity();
                addThisToSpinner = newSpinner.spinner;
                newSpinner.loadSpinnerData();
```

I tried to instantiate my new activity and to call it and to add dynamically one item to spinner but don't know how exactly. Adding items if they are in the same class is not a problem. Problem is how to call handler(spinner) from another activity (fragment). How does it effect adapter options?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Spinner can use SimpleCursorAdapter as Adapter. When you want to add new value to your spinner, you add new value to DB, then refresh the adapter cursor, it will load new value to your spinner.

Comment: so better solution is to add value to database and then forward that value to spinner. Ok, but how to programmatically do that? How to code it? How to add values to database from fragment and read them?